# Python 2.7.9 Getting error:TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time

This is occurring on the following code line:

`epoch_time = int(time.mktime(time.strptime( time.strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", status.sensorBGLTimestamp ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timetuple()) - time.timezone )`

Anyone able to help with why?

Comment: include the full traceback also please

Comment: `status.sensorBGLTimestamp` is certainly a `datetime.datetime` object and you're using `time` module (which expects a time.localtime() / 9-item sequence as input). But I have trouble understanding what you really want to do here.

Comment: I'm trying to take a value from an external source `sensorBGLTimestamp` and reformat it.  I've borrowed the code and don't know a great deal of python. The piece that follows is:

`epoch_time = epoch_time - time.localtime(epoch_time).tm_isdst*3600

with open('latest_sg.json','w') as text_file:
    text_file.write('"value":"{0}","sgv":{0},"type":"sgv","dateString":"{1}","date":{2}'.format( status.sensorBGL, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", time.localtime(epoch_time)) , epoch_time*1000 ))`

And it's been added to provide a file for a REST API upload separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simply get the epoch time, you should use

```
import calendar
import time

calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
```

**Returns:**
`1473881423`